# How to autofill references to different tabs in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of companies in a "dashboard" tab and all companies have their financials in tabs named after them (same names as listed in column A, cf picture attached). I would like to autofill the tab name in the formula. For example, EBITDA info is always in cell D12, so I would like V2 and V3 to automatically be ='1stdibs'!D12 and ='Abbott'!D12. Is there any way to get there?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `INDIRECT` formula to do this

example

`=INDIRECT(A3 & "!D12")` will reference and return the value stored in sheet **1stdibs** cell **D12**

in order for this to work you have to use the `&` symbol to concatenate the cell that you want to reference with the sheet name.  Notice the `!` at the beginning of the cell reference, this is required to separate the cell reference from the sheet reference